# SDL_IsShapedWindow is raising an error while creating apk file using buildozer

Tags: kivy, kivymd, buildozer, python-for-android, p4a

I am using kivy, kivymd to create .apk for android platform. I have tried 3 platforms (google colab, github workflows, and ubuntu buildozer manual way), but I am still not able to create the .apk file, every time I solve one error, a new error pops up. now
I am getting error in the SDL_IsShapedWindow. Here is the log of errors. I don't know what this is. I have installed every possible libraries my application may need, but still apk is not building. Please can someone suggest a solution.

```
Error compiling Cython file:
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    ...
[DEBUG]:            return SDL_IsShapedWindow(self.win)
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:        def set_shape(self, shape, mode, cutoff, color_key):
[DEBUG]:            cdef SDL_Surface * sdl_shape
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:            cpdef SDL_WindowShapeMode sdl_window_mode
[DEBUG]:                  ^
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx:440:14: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Error compiling Cython file:
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    ...
[DEBUG]:            # Open all available joysticks
[DEBUG]:            cdef int joy_i
[DEBUG]:            for joy_i in range(SDL_NumJoysticks()):
[DEBUG]:                SDL_JoystickOpen(joy_i)
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:            SDL_SetEventFilter(_event_filter, <void *>self)
[DEBUG]:                               ^
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx:266:27: Cannot assign type 'int (void *, SDL_Event *) except? -1 nogil' to 'SDL_EventFilter *'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'int (void *, SDL_Event *) except? -1 nogil'.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Error compiling Cython file:
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    ...
[DEBUG]:            wx, wy = self.get_window_pos()
[DEBUG]:            return x - wx, y - wy
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:        def set_custom_titlebar(self, titlebar_widget):
[DEBUG]:            SDL_SetWindowBordered(self.win, SDL_FALSE)
[DEBUG]:            return SDL_SetWindowHitTest(self.win,custom_titlebar_handler_callback,<void *>titlebar_widget)
[DEBUG]:                                                 ^
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx:796:45: Cannot assign type 'SDL_HitTestResult (SDL_Window *, const SDL_Point *, void *) except * nogil' to 'SDL_HitTest'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'SDL_HitTestResult (SDL_Window *, const SDL_Point *, void *) except * nogil'.
Exception in thread background thread for pid 53645:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx

  STDOUT:
/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:384: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a_arm64-v8a/build/other_builds/kivy/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
warning: kivy/core/window/../../../kivy/lib/../include/config.pxi:2:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310

kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx:796:45: Cannot assign type 'SDL_HitTestResult (SDL_Window *, const SDL_Point *, void *) except * nogil' to 'SDL_HitTest'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'SDL_HitTestResult (SDL_Window *, const SDL_Point *, void *) except * nogil'.


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1262, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 680, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 99, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 158, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1028, in build_arch
    self.build_cython_components(arch)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1053, in build_cython_components
    self.cythonize_build(env=env)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 38, in cythonize_build
    super().cythonize_build(env, build_dir=build_dir)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1101, in cythonize_build
    self.cythonize_file(env, build_dir, join(root, filename))
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 59, in cythonize_file
    super().cythonize_file(env, build_dir, filename)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1090, in cythonize_file
    shprint(python_command, "-c"
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/das0206/Desktop/Kivy/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
```

I tried customizing buildozer.spec file as well, I searched many platforms for .spec file customization and tried implementing every possible customization but still getting errors.
If my .spec file as any problem, please guide me.
Here is the .spec file configuration:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = com.my.app

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = myKivyMDApp/

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg, fonts/*.ttf

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png, assets/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# font
# presplash.font_path = path_to_your_font.ttf

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.2.1,kivymd==1.1.1,pillow,cython==3.0.2

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

# Specify the fonts directory relative to your project directory
presplash.fonts = fonts/


#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.10.10

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.2.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 32

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 23b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class which extends PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk res directory.
# The option may be used in three ways, the value may contain one or zero ':'
# Some examples:
# 1) A file to add to resources, legal resource names contain ['a-z','0-9','_']
# android.add_resources = my_icons/all-inclusive.png:drawable/all_inclusive.png
# 2) A directory, here  'legal_icons' must contain resources of one kind
# android.add_resources = legal_icons:drawable
# 3) A directory, here 'legal_resources' must contain one or more directories, 
# each of a resource kind:  drawable, xml, etc...
# android.add_resources = legal_resources
#android.add_resources =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = True

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Copy these files to src/main/res/xml/ (used for example with intent-filters)
#android.res_xml = PATH_TO_FILE,

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (str) screenOrientation to set for the main activity.
# Valid values can be found at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element
#android.manifest.orientation = fullSensor

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) Skip byte compile for .py files
# android.no-byte-compile-python = False

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk or aar).
# android.release_artifact = aab

# (str) The format used to package the app for debug mode (apk or aar).
# android.debug_artifact = apk

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =



#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Can anyone tell me what the error could be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by specifying the version of Cython I wanted to install. The version that worked for me is this:
`python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.33 virtualenv`.

This assumes you are building the dependencies yourself and not using the `ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action@v1`. Regardless, you can find the yml file example here: https://github.com/BukiOffor/hydra-python-api/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml